# How do I prevent workspace switching with multiple windows in gnome 3?

Tags: workspaces, dock, ubuntu-dock

For example, I have windows of my browser open, I want one to be open in one workspace and one in another. In the dock it shows multiple windows open, and when I click it it switches me to the other workspace where the other window is. Is there any way I can prevent it switching workspaces like this, and just show the windows open in my current workspace?

Comment: I have found a solution, but that uses the Ubuntu Dock, and I am using Dash to Dock.

Comment: Same thing will work, Ubuntu Dock is just a fork of Dash to Dock.